# How to snprintf gracefully?

Tags: c, ascii, printf

How to gracefully use `snprintf` function or some another function from standard `C` library to fill the memory by ASCII representation of an array of `unsigned char`?

```
char data[16];
char dataRepresentation[33];
...
for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        snprintf(&dataRepresentation[i * 2], 3, "%02x", (unsigned char) data[i])
```

Is it the easiest way to get the ASCII representation?

Comment: `dataRepresentation[i * 2]` should be `&dataRepresentation[i * 2]`. `data[i]` should be `(unsigned)data[i]`.

Comment: @Banthar: `(unsigned)` won't help. You need `((unsigned char *)data)[i]` to be correct, or just an `(unsigned char)` cast to be sloppy but probably-okay.

Comment: Assuming the code in the question is corrected so it compiles, it's going to clobber one byte past the end of `dataRepresentation` when the last `snprintf()` call writes its terminating `'\0'`.  Quick fix: change the declaration to `char dataRepresentation[32]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of bit-twiddling will go much faster:

```
char data[16];
char dataRepresentation[2 * sizeof data];
static const char master[] = "01234567890abcdef";
...
for (i = 0; i < sizeof data; ++i)
{
     dataRepresentation[i * 2] = master[0xF&(data[i]>>4)];
     dataRepresentation[i * 2 + 1] = master[data[i]&0xF];
}
```

Beware that I haven't actually compiled this code.

Comment: `dataRepresentation[i * 2] = master[data[i]>>4]; dataRepresentation[i * 2 + 1] = master[data[i]&0xF];`

Comment: Be careful about signedness!!

Comment: Believe me I've seen lots of sign issues... it was a bug in my code I've now fixed. I said I did not run it ;-)